# jquery disable option in select if we chose this option in another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I should do to have no dupplicates in selects? If my select1 = subject1, select2 and select3 option = subject1 should be disabled and if select1 = subject1, select2 = subject2, select3 options subject1 and subject2 should be disabled. Sorry for bad English ;(

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $('document').ready(function() {
   $('select.remRep').on('change', function() {
    var index1 = $(this).val();
       $.each($('select.remRep option'), function() {
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
       }); 
    switch (index1) {
     case "1" :
      $('select.remRep option[value="1"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
     break;
     case "2" :
      $('select.remRep option[value="2"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
     break;
     case "3" :
      $('select.remRep option[value="3"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
     break;
          case "4" :
      $('select.remRep option[value="4"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
     break;
          case "5" :
      $('select.remRep option[value="5"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
     break;
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="sel1" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
    <option value="4">Subject4</option>
    <option value="5">Subject5</option>
</select>
<select id="sel3" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
    <option value="4">Subject4</option>
    <option value="5">Subject5</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
This updates all options but NOT the current one.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  // put in yopur global scope.
  var previous;
  
  // add previous/current value in previous var when input in focus
  $('select.remRep').on('focus', function () {
    previous = this.value;
    
  // when the input detects a change
  }).on('change', function() {
    var t = $(this);
    
    //update the previous value to be enabled
    $('option[value=' + previous + ']').removeAttr('disabled');
    
    // disable new value in other inputs
    $('option[value=' + t.val() + ']').not(t).attr('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
    <option value="4">Subject4</option>
    <option value="5">Subject5</option>
</select>
<select id="sel3" class="remRep">
  <option value="0">none</option>
    <option value="1">Subject1</option>
    <option value="2">Subject2</option>
    <option value="3">Subject3</option>
    <option value="4">Subject4</option>
    <option value="5">Subject5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

```
$('#s1').find('option').eq(0).attr('disabled', true);
$('#s1 option[value="1"]').attr('disabled', true);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y76xj2up/)

**Note:** with `attr()` use `attr('disabled', 'true/false');`